# Does a pulley rotate due to internal friction between the pulley and string?

Tags: rotation

How does a frictionless  pulley rotate?

Comment: Can you clarify you problem /confusion in the question body so that the answer to the question can be more precise.

Comment: I recommend you to properly explain the situation in [the body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/530908/edit) so that the answer can be specific, precise and relevant to you. Otherwise two things are possible 1) either the question gets closed as "needs details or clarity" 2) you don't get the answer you want.

Comment: Is it fine @Johan Liebert

Comment: If there was no friction between the line and the sheave, then it wouldn't matter whether the sheave was free to rotate or not. A frictionless pully does not _need_ to rotate.

Comment: A "frictionless" pulley is a convenient fiction (cf. [spherical cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow)). It is also usually assumed that the mass of the sheave is much smaller than the mass of the relevant bodies, so it is also common to assume a "massless" pulley and a "massless" rope. In the usual vernacular, "frictionless" refers to the pulley's axle rotating in its bearings, not to the surface of the groove where the rope is: there you are can assume that the friction is high enough so the rope does not slip as the pulley rotates.

Answer (score 1):

A frictionless pulley is a pulley that experiences **no losses** due to friction. So, it is referring to *kinetic* friction, since only kinetic friction causes energy losses (energy released as heat). It thus essentially means: no kinetic friction between the pulley and its axle, between axle bearings or anything else like that.

There *can* be static frictions present, which indeed is a necessity between pulley-surface and string. Because static friction does not cause any energy losses.

Comment: Is static friction then the cause of rotation of pulley?

Comment: @NimittArora Yes.

Comment: Can there be static friction in the absence of kinetic friction?

Comment: @JohanLiebert Are you referring to something specific? Yes there can certainly in general be static friction without kinetic friction present.

Comment: E.g. if the string does not slip, the relative speed between the rope and the pulley at the point of contact is 0.